# Add error message to field with codeigniter form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

With Codeigniter you can validate forms with the form_validation library. However I don't use this all the time but I like to use the `form_error('fieldname')` function.

Is it possible to push a error message to a field manually without doing `form_validation->run()`.

Answer (score 6):

I found a Codeigniter way to add the functionality I want. By extending the `system/libraries/Form_validation.php`.

First create file: `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`

Then extend the `CI_Form_validation` class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: william
 * Date: 02/02/2016
 * Time: 22:56
 */

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

    /**
     * set error message
     *
     * sets the error message associated with a particular field
     *
     * @param   string  $field  Field name
     * @param   string  $error      Error message
     */
    public function setError($field, $error){
        $this->_field_data[$field]['error'] = $error;
    }

}
```

Now you can use the `form_validation->setError('fieldname','error')` to manualy set error messages:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if (/* your validation outside of the form_validation */) {
            $this->form_validation->setError('username', 'Invalid login credentials');      
        }

        $this->load->view('test');
    }

}
```

*Note! Use this when you want to do some custom validation without using a callback*

Answer (score 2):

No, that function is only designed to work with the Form_validation library.

Comment: can i add image validation error in **validation_errors** of codeigniter?

Comment: sir, can it possible to get only error in validation_errors();